# jQuery - Select current table row values

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

When someone clicks on the Download button in my table, I want to pass the date values from that particular row to a function. Currently I can only pass the date values from the first table row.

This is the selector I'm using:

```
$(this).parent().find('#period-start');
```

Which always returns:

```
[<td id=​"period-start">​5/1/2013​</td>]
```

I've tried combinations of the parent, child, find and closest selectors, but haven't been able to stumble across the correct one to grab the date values from the current row. Thanks.

**Table**

```
<table id="tblStatements" class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Period Starting</th>
                    <th>Period Ending</th>
                    <th>Download</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

<tr>
  <td id='period-start'>5/1/2013</td>
  <td id='period-end'>5/31/2013</td>
  <td><button type='submit'>Download</button></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td id='period-start'>4/1/2013</td>
  <td id='period-end'>4/30/2013</td>
  <td><button type='submit'>Download</button></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td id='period-start'>3/1/2013</td>
  <td id='period-end'>3/31/2013</td>
  <td><button type='submit'>Download</button></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Don't give same IDs on each `TD`, this is not a good practice

Comment: In fact that is invalid HTML. An ID *must* be unique. If you want to attach the same behavior to different elements, use classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**ID**'s are always supposed to be *unique* in HTML. So, you might try out this, w/o using an ID:

```
// Get the first td
var periodStart = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:eq(0)').text();  

// Get the second td
var periodEnd = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:eq(1)').text();
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pCDNz/)

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered. I marked this one as correct as the Fiddle demo was particularly helpful to me. I had to use $('button'). rather than $('this'). to return the value I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Use this - *don't use duplicate ID's though, use class instead*

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('#period-start');
```

or -

```
$(this).closest('td').siblings('#period-start');
```

Comment: I think children better than find

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 $(this).parent().siblings('#period-start');
```

**Make sure all your ids is unique..your HTML is invalid.... change it to class and try this**

```
  $(this).parent().siblings('.period-start');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use more then one element with the same id use class insidead.

```
<tr>
  <td class='period-start'>5/1/2013</td>
  <td class='period-end'>5/31/2013</td>
  <td><button type='submit'>Download</button></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td class='period-start'>4/1/2013</td>
  <td class='period-end'>4/30/2013</td>
  <td><button type='submit'>Download</button></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td class='period-start'>3/1/2013</td>
  <td class='period-end'>3/31/2013</td>
  <td><button type='submit'>Download</button></td>
</tr>
```

and use this code to select proper element

```
$(this).parents('tr').find('.period-start');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$.trim($(this).closest('tr').find('[id="period-start"]').html());//this gives start date
```